# Unable to convert address to symbols with symbolicatecrash (XCode 4.0.2 - target device iPad)

Tags: ipad, xcode4, symbolicatecrash

I read through many blogs and the forum but unable to find the answer for my issue. So I am looking for your help.

I am using Xcode 4.2 and my app target device is iPad. Here are steps I did to test how symbolicatecrash works :)

I run Product/Archive (Release mode) to have ipa file and install this file on iPad. Also run build for Archiving to have *.app and *.dSYM package. Run the app on iPad to get crash file. After these steps, I put all *.crash and these two packages in one folder. symbolicatecrash runs through but it does not convert address to symbols :(, I still see addresses on the crashed thread instead of function names.

I did config build following (http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/symbolizingcrashdumps.html)

- Generate Debug Symbols YES
- Debug Information Format DWARF with dSYM
- File Deployment Postprocessing YES
- Strip Linked Product YES Use
- Separate Strip YES
- Strip Debug Symbols During Copy N

Please let me know if I need to do anything else to make it work.
Thanks,

Comment: Your question title references Xcode 4.0.2 but your question text references Xcode 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than one version of Xcode installed on your computer? I had the latest version installed in /Developer and an older version still installed in /Developer_old. When I ran symbolicatecrash with the -v flag, I saw that it was looking in Developer_old for resources.

I opened symbolicatecrash in a text editor and modified the getSymbolDirPaths function, adding this line after chomp $foundPath:

```
$foundPath =~ s/_old//; # don't use the old version we kept installed
```

When I ran symbolicatecrash again, it worked!

Just a guess but hopefully this will help someone.